# Best Practice Conditionally Rendering JSX ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am curious regarding best practice in conditionally rendering JSX in a react component, In the component user data is being fetched, if the user array is less than 1 I would like to display the new user text otherwise I do not want to display anything.  My code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);


  useEffect(()=> {
// where I would set the user state 
  },[])

  return (
    <>
      {!users || users.length < 1 ? (
        <div className="section-heading">New Users</div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

This logic works, but I am curious about best practice regarding conditionally rendering jsx and why another method might be better than the method I am currently using.

Comment: It's in their [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) so it's fine.  Any attempt to answer this would be opinionated.  I don't like complex ternary renders, but sometimes it's just the easiest path forward.  Some would prefer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends solely on you coding style. As you know React is pretty unopinionated and there are no such coding practise that is enforced.

However I would suggest that you stick with early return pattern which will greatly improve your code readability.

That being said, something like this would help you handle multiple conditional logic

```js
if (users && users.length) {
    return null
}

return (
    <div className="section-heading">New Users</div>
  );
```

Comment: is this what you mean by the early return pattern, the logic of the if statement as opposed to doing it inside my component's return

Comment: @RobertTerrell please check updated answer, your logic is a bit confusing to me, so I hope I got it right :D

Comment: understood I've seen this method before, and this seems to be a lot more readable